# cannot access r_emailaddress using LinkedIn v2/me

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I've successfully implemented LinkedIn OAuth functionality, but I need to retrieve some information from LinkedIn.
I've successfully get r_liteprofile data after using access_token(by second last step of LinkedIn). But I need r_emailaddress as well.
But When I am trying to get email address it is returning me the error

**"Not enough permissions to access: GET /me"**
[image]

I would appreciate any help from you guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've used a different way to get the email address.

Just used the following approach and it works for me

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/clientAwareMemberHandles?q=members&projection=(elements*(primary,type,handle~))&oauth2_access_token=".$token